# Tooltip de Bootstrap desaparece al pasar sobre nodo hijo

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, interfaz-gráfica, tooltip

Tengo una serie de elementos construidos de esta forma:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '.hasTooltip',
    trigger: "hover"
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Texto del tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <i class="fas fa-user m-0"></i>                                
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-3 hasTooltip" title="Otro texto del tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span>Cualquier elemento hijo</span>                                
</button>
```

Entonces, cuando coloco el cursor sobre un elemento que tiene un Tooltip el comportamiento es correcto y se muestra la ayuda que quiero mostrar. El problema sucede cuando el cursor se pone sobre cualquier elemento hijo.

En ese momento el tooltip desaparece de repente o se reposiciona en la esquina superior izquierda de la página, y se rompe el comportamiento habitual. Ya no funciona más. No importa si pongo un icono, un div o simplemente un elemento span.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este fallo?

Answer (score 1):

semánticamente hablando no es posible ya que un spam no puede estar dentro de un botón.
https://github.com/calebjacob/tooltipster/issues/501
esto pasa con varios pluggin.
la solución seria el uso de popover:

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/J7nDz/1035/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap 3 Popover HTML Example</h3>
    <span data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="left" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-default" >Click me</span>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-4">
           <img width="88px" height="88px"src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/816404989392211968/Wv_8ZDrX_400x400.jpg"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
           <h4>
           Justin Trudeau <br/>
           <small>
             Prime minister of Canada
           </small>
           </h4>
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
           Follow
           </button>
           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
           View profile
           </button>         
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true, 
        content: function() {
              return $('#popover-content').html();
            }
    });
```

[Recurso de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174259/4717133)

Comment: Dejando un momento de lado la semántica, hablamos de una funcionalidad que iba perfectamente bien en versiones anteriores de Bootstrap y que ahora ha dejado de funcionar en la 5.0 beta 1. Estoy busco la manera de que sí lo haga sin tener que regresar a una versión anterior. Tu sugerencia del popover es interesante pero no se ajusta a lo que necesito.

Comment: ok entiendo... y si le agregas el toltip a los dos elementos???

Comment: Tampoco funciona. He probado a publicar en el panel de incidencias de Bootstrap y alguien me ha respondido que podría utilizar una regla css para todos los hijos de un elemento que tenga un tooltip anulando todos los eventos de ratón: `.btn *{pointer-events: none !important}`. Eso soluciona el problema y lo hace funcionar como debería según mis pruebas, pero no pienso que sea la forma más correcta de hacerlo. Deberían arreglarlo en la siguiente revisión de Bootstrap.

Comment: dame. un oar de horas para profundizar.

Answer (score 0):

Según una respuesta en el hilo que he abierto en el [panel de incidencias oficial](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32880) de esta release de Bootstrap, se puede sortear el error añadiendo algo así al css:

```
.hasTooltip *{
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

La clase `.hasTooltip` me la acabo de inventar para ejemplificar cualquier elemento que tenga un tooltip, porque esto no solo sucede en botones.

Obviamente se trata de un apaño y no creo que deban dejarlo así, sino que deberían solucionarlo en la próxima revisión de la versión 5.